# Grails: transients variable not accessible in custom validator?

Tags: validation, grails, transient

I cannot find the reason why `obj.confirmPassword` is always null.
If `confirmPassword` is not part of transients, all work fine.

```
String confirmPassword
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

static transients = ['springSecurityService', 'confirmPassword']

static constraints = {
   username blank: false, unique: true, minSize: 4, maxSize: 64
   password blank: false, nullable: false, minSize: 4, maxSize: 64, validator: {password, obj ->
      def password2 = obj.confirmPassword
      password2 == password ? true : ['invalid.matchingpasswords']
   }
   userFullname blank: false, minSize: 4, maxSize: 64
}
```

this one throw NullPointer when save() is called:

```
String confirmPasswordField
    static transients = ['springSecurityService', 'confirmPasswordField']

    static constraints = {
        confirmPasswordField bindable: true, nullable:true, blank: false
        username blank: false, unique: true, minSize: 4, maxSize: 64
        password blank: false, nullable: false, minSize: 4, maxSize: 64, validator: {password, obj ->
            def confirmPassword = obj.confirmPasswordField
            confirmPassword == password ? true : ['invalid.matchingpasswords']
        }
        userFullname blank: false, minSize: 4, maxSize: 64
    }
```

If I comment all the stuff regarding confirmPasswordField - save() is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons transients are no longer auto-bound. But you can easily make it work by adding in a 'bindable' constraint (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html). You can use confirmPassword like this.

```
confirmPassword(bindable: true, nullable:true, blank: false)
```